# how to add from address to mail box when the form data submission?

Tags: html, forms, mailto

In my HTML, I have a form submission section. I use the `mailto` attribute to submit the form. It is working fine, but what I am trying is if the client enters their email address in the form, then submit the form, that email id is automatically entered to the `from` address of the mail box, but I cant find a solution for this.

```html
<form action="mailto:sidhik64742@gmail.com" method="GET"> 
                <div class="row pl-3">
                  <div class=" col-1">
                    <span class="fa mr-2 fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-11 pr-5 ">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control w-75 form-background" name="fullname" id="fullName" placeholder="Full Name" required>
                  </div>
                  <br>
                  <br>
                  <div class="col-1">
                    <span class="fa fa-envelope-open" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-11 pr-5">
                    <input type="email" class="form-control w-75 form-background" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" required> 
                  </div>
                  <br>
                  <br>
                  <div class="col-1">
                    <span class="fa fa-phone" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-11 pr-5">
                    <input type="mobile" class="form-control w-75 form-background" name="mobile" id="phone" placeholder="phone" required>
                  </div>
                  <br>
                  <br>
                  <div class="col-1">
                    <span class="fa mr-2 fa-edit" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-11 pr-5">
                    <textarea class="form-control w-75 textarea form-background" rows="5" cols="40" name="comment" id="message" form="Myform" placeholder="Enter feedback here..." ></textarea>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-12 p-3">
                    <input class="btn btn-primary button" id="" type="submit" value="Submit">
                  </div>

                </div>
              </form>
```

Comment: Hi Sidhik, you will need to use Javascript to create a variable for the email field content. When the submit button is pressed you can run a function like updateEmail() that updates the reference in your mailto:. I would research a Javascript framework such as ReactJS.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with PHP if you want(I would recommend changing the form method to 'POST' if you decide to do so):

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['email'])){
$email = $_POST['email'];
$this = "";
// You would repeat the above for all the form attributes and place them below how you want
$body = "
This is where the body of the email will go. You can put variables in here like {$this}
";
$mail = mail("xxxx@gmail.com","The subject of the email",$body,"From: {$email}");
if($mail){
echo "Mail sent.";
} else {
echo "Mail not sent.";
}
}
?>
```

Hope this helps.